# Оценка оптимальности структуры БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация

У меня есть проект на подобие всезнающего бота, но попроще. Есть таблица `слов`, `ответов` на них, `новых`, еще непроверенных, слов и таблица `стандартных ответов`(если ответов пока что нет).

Как это будет работать?

- Если слово есть - из таблицы ответов выбираются все ответы, имеющие
  привязку к слову. Если их несколько методом рандома выбираем один.
- Если слова нет - его заносит в БД и на выходе показывает один из
  стандартных ответов, список которых перечислен в таблице
  `стандартные`. Так же после вывода ответа на странице появляется
  новая кнопка "добавить ответ" и при вводе значения ответ отправляется
  в таблицу "новые ответы" на проверку администраторами.

Меня напрягает что такая структура нечто неоптимальная. Может стоит соединить таблицу ответов и вопросов? Тогда будут строки типа "вопрос-ответ", а на данный момент все связано по ID. Это вопрос оптимизации о которой я почти ничего не знаю.

Comment: если вы соедините их в одну таблицу то к одному вопросу сможет быть только один ответ. а первым пунктом вы написали "_выбираются все ответы, имеющие привязку_". так что другого варианта хранения у вас нет. либо вы начнете дублировать вопросы и искать по тексту. вот это точно будет криво и не оптимально.

Comment: У меня есть странный вариант добавлять новые ответы к слову через запятую. Тогда это вроде как не будет засорять таблицу лишними строками. Разделять запятые и делать другие действия уже в PHP. Может при небольшом количестве ответов это рациональнее?

Comment: Если не считать, что серьезное удлинение существующей строки переполнит блок в котором лежит запись и она будет перенесена в другой. при этом в старом блоке останется ссылка и при любом обращении к такой строке субд будет вынуждена по очереди пройтись по таким ссылкам что бы добраться до записи. С другой стороны за отдельными ответами то же лазить придется в разные места. В принципе можно хранить и к слову список прямо в одной колонке, сделав ее типа text, если вы абсолютно уверены что любой доступ будет со стороны слов и не придется как то искать ответы сами по себе

Comment: А вообще, то что вы в данный момент хотите решается не реляционными, а документарными (noSQL) Базами данных. Но тут надо смотреть на все задачи стоящие перед системой в комплексе. потому как очень многие виды данных в документарные БД нормально не ложатся и приходится  собирать систему на костылях

Comment: @Mike я тоже думал что правильней было бы использовать не реляционные БД, но я решил что пока что рано(или мне лень) их учить и решил сделать известными мне средствами. Спасибо за внимание и объяснения.